# If $x^5=2$, find $\frac{x}{x^2+1}+\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}+\frac{x^3}{x+1}+\frac{x^4}{x^3+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $x^5=2$, find
> $$\frac{x}{x^2+1}+\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}+\frac{x^3}{x+1}+\frac{x^4}{x^3+1}$$

My attempt-

Since $x^5=2,x^6=2x,x^7=2x^2..$and so on

The equation is equivalent to
$$x^5\left(\frac{1}{2x+x^4}+\frac{1}{2x^2+x^3}+\frac{1}{x^3+x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4+x}\right)$$

Which simplifies to
$$2\left[\frac{3x^4+7x^3+5x^2+8x+12}{2x^4+6x^3+4x^2+6x+12}\right]$$
Now I am struck here.

Any help will be appreciated.

Note: Please don't use root tables and complex numbers too!

Comment: What is your goal?  If $x^5 = 2$ then $x = 2^{1/5}$, and your expression comes out to about $2.37$.

Comment: I want to solve it algebraicly with process

Comment: Yes, but how simplified do you want it?  Do you know for certain that it has a nice reduced form?  Otherwise $\frac{2^{1/5}}{2^{2/5}+1}+\frac{2^{2/5}}{2^{4/5}+1}+\frac{2^{3/5}}{2^{1/5}+1}+\frac{2^{4/5}}{2^{3/5}+1}$ is perfectly valid.

Comment: Are you allowing the possibility that $x$ takes complex number values?

Comment: @paw88789 no  it is not allowed

Comment: @DMcMor I just wanted a nice simplified answer and I think your answer is also correct

Comment: Are we assuming that $x\in\mathbb{R}$, or might $x\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: X=Real not complex @robjon

Comment: @ArchitPasayat: It would be nice to add that to the question statement. Of course, since you are looking for an "exact" answer, $2^{1/5}$ is what gets substituted for $x$ (not a numerical approximation). Then, one can use any complex value for $2^{1/5}$, if one pleases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working mod $x^5-2$,
$$
\scriptsize\frac{3x^3}{1+x}=x^3\frac{1+x^5}{1+x}=x^3-x^4+x^5-x^6+x^7=2-2x+2x^2+x^3-x^4\tag1
$$
$$
\scriptsize\frac{5x}{1+x^2}=x\frac{1+x^{10}}{1+x^2}=x-x^3+x^5-x^7+x^9=2+x-2x^2-x^3+2x^4\tag2
$$
$$
\scriptsize\frac{9x^4}{1+x^3}=x^4\frac{1+x^{15}}{1+x^3}=x^4-x^7+x^{10}-x^{13}+x^{16}=4+8x-2x^2-4x^3+x^4\tag3
$$
$$
\scriptsize\frac{17x^2}{1+x^4}=x^2\frac{1+x^{20}}{1+x^4}=x^2-x^6+x^{10}-x^{14}+x^{18}=4-2x+x^2+8x^3-4x^4\tag4
$$
Adding $\frac13\text{(1)}+\frac15\text{(2)}+\frac19\text{(3)}+\frac1{17}\text{(4)}$, we get
$$
\scriptsize\frac{x^3}{1+x}+\frac{x}{1+x^2}+\frac{x^4}{1+x^3}+\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}=\frac{1336+233x+79x^2+122x^3-44x^4}{765}\tag5
$$

Comment: Note that if $x^5=1$, then $\frac{x^3}{1+x}+\frac{x}{1+x^2}+\frac{x^4}{1+x^3}+\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}=2$, no matter which fifth root of $1$ is used.

Answer (score 3):

I used [Sage cell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) to calculate this.

```
var("X")
F.<x> = NumberField(X^5 - 2)
y = x/(x^2 + 1) + x^2/(x^4 + 1) + x^3/(x + 1) + x^4/(x^3 + 1)
print(y)
print(y.minpoly())
```

Output:

```
-44/765*x^4 + 122/765*x^3 + 79/765*x^2 + 233/765*x + 1336/765
x^5 - 1336/153*x^4 + 1556/51*x^3 - 8182/153*x^2 + 7210/153*x - 12806/765
```

In the output, the first line is the sum, and the second line is the minimal polynomial of that sum.

None of these is nice enough to be an intended answer. Thus I suspect that the question is slightly wrong.

---

One possibility is to change $x^5 = 2$ to $x^5 = 1$. Then it is easy to evaluate that the sum is equal to $2$.

Comment: Yeah I also suspect that the question is wrong

Answer (score 1):

$$
y=\frac{x}{x^2+1}+\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}+\frac{x^3}{x+1}+\frac{x^4}{x^3+1}$$
$$
=\frac{x (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1) (x^6 - x^5 + 2 x^4 + x + 1)}{(x + 1) (x^2 + 1) (x^2 - x + 1) (x^4 + 1)}$$
$$
=\frac{8 + 5 2^{1/5} + 7 2^{2/5} + 3 2^{3/5} + 6 2^{4/5}}{3 + 2 2^{1/5} + 3 2^{2/5} + 2^{3/5} + 3 2^{4/5}}$$

$$x=\sqrt[\large 5]{2}\approx 1.1487  \implies y\approx 2.37411
$$